# d3 change function of button with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, d3.js

I have two d3 column charts (`#salesChart` and `#bonusChart`) on the same page. Above them is a button
`<button id="sortSalesAscending">Sort Sales Ascending</button>`
that sorts only the sales chart. Next to the button is an "unchecked" checkbox `<input id="linkChartsCheckbox" type="checkbox"> Link Charts<br>`.

What I want is that when the checkbox is "checked", a subsequent click of the button will sort **both** charts. Then when unchecked, a subsequent click of the button reverts to sorting only the sales chart again. The act of checking/unchecking the checkbox should not make the button "run", it just changes **which** code the button should run when it is clicked.

(I realize this functionality doesn't make sense in isolation like this, but it is part of a bigger set of charts that will all be linked or not linked).

Here is the code for the button sorting only the sales chart. This works.

```
d3.select("#sortSalesAscending")
    .on("click", function() {
        d3.selectAll("#salesChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
            })
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i) {
                return i * sortDelay;
            })
            .duration(sortDuration)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
            });
    });
```

Here is the code for sorting both charts. This works (the sales chart and bonus chart both sort by the sales data).

```
d3.select("#sortSalesAscending")
    .on("click", function() {
        d3.selectAll("#salesChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
            })
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i) {
                return i * 50;
            })
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
            });
        d3.selectAll("#bonusChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
            })
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i) {
                return i * 50;
            })
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
            });
    });
```

I would prefer not to use jQuery, but resorted to it after failing miserably using pure JS. Here is my logic

```
$('#linkChartsCheckbox').change(function(){
    cb = $(this);
    cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
    var foo = $(this).val();
    if ( foo === true ) {
        ...put code for sorting both graphs here... 
    } else {
        ...put code for sorting only first graph here...
    }
}
```

This sort of worked once, but then I undid something and lost it. Also, the button would not work at all unless it was checked/unchecked once first. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the sorting to happen on the button click event or when you click the checkbox?

Comment: On the button click. The state of the checkbox ("checked" or "unchecked") would change which code the button runs when the button is clicked. Will clarify in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to separate the checkbox checked/unchecked from the if/else statement for the button. Thanks @Orry Vandermeulen for the nudge in that direction. Also I didn't need to set a global `var` for the state of the checkbox. I could just check this way `if ($('#linkChartsCheckbox').is(':checked')) {...`

```
$('#linkChartsCheckbox').change(function(){
    cb = $(this);
    cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));}
})

d3.select("#sortSalesAscending")            
    .on("click", function() {
        if ($('#linkChartsCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
            d3.selectAll("#salesChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                    return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
                })
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d, i) {
                    return i * 50;
                })
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
                });
            d3.selectAll("#bonusChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                        return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
                })
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d, i) {
                    return i * 50;
                })
                .duration(1000)
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
                });
        } else {
            d3.selectAll("#salesChart g.bar").sort(function(a, b) {
                    return d3.ascending(a.sales, b.sales) || d3.ascending(a.name, b.name);
                })
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d, i) {
                    return i * sortDelay;
                })
                .duration(sortDuration)
                .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                    return "translate(" + xScale(i) + ",0)";
                });             
        }
    });
```